# script encoder for IDS test

Tags: ids, python, encoding

Encoding a payload is a means of evading antivirus or IDS.
With regard to scripts is there a way to do the same thing?

For instance, is it possible to encode a python script in order test intrusion prevention systems?
This script here https://github.com/SecuraBV/CVE-2020-1472 ,is there anything I can use to disguise it in order to test against a Windows Server behind IDS system?

I know metasploit can use different encoders like shikata ga nai or whatever.

But what I'd like to use is not part of the above mentioned framework

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the IDS is designed to look for and what the exploit is. Is it looking for the script code? Or is it looking for the effects in the traffic?

If it is looking for the effects on the wire, then there will be little one can do to hide that from the IDS, no matter if it is a script or a compiled binary.

If the target needs to experience the traffic in a particular way in order for the exploit to work, then that particular way will be detectable on the wire.

Comment: thanks actually it's just a question of testing if a specific script disguise it through an encoder (I mentioned shikata ga nai) is able to evade a layer 7 firewall (which I know it's basically more than just IDS) The script itself gets caught by the firewall whose related action is drop but what about if strong encoding is applied?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to encode a Python script, such as using base64 encoding or using a tool like pyminifier or pyarmor to obfuscate the code. However, it's important to note that while encoding can help evade detection by some security systems, it is not foolproof, and more advanced systems may still be able to detect the encoded script.